# time comlpexity of enumeration all the subsets

Tags: time-complexity

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   enumerate all subsets of size i = 2^n
   each subset of size i takes o(nlogn) to search a solution
   from all these solution I want to search the minimum subset of size S.
}
```

I want to know the complexity of this algorithm it'is `2^n O(nlogn*n)=o(2^n n²)` ??

Comment: i can not get any sense into the "code" you posted.. please improve your question.

Comment: from a given set of number (takes o(nlogn)) I want to enumerate all the subsets of size i. Every subsets of size i takes o(nlogn) to solve. From all these subset of size i want to find the minimum cost. Hope it's clear now

Comment: what do you want to solve? what is a minimum subset of size S? if the subset you looking for contais S elements, the minimum is the sum of the containd numbers? what takes o(nlogn) at the beginning? do you sort them first?

Comment: yes in the begening I want to sort them this operation takes o(nlogn).
the subset contais S elements and the minimum is the sum of the containd numbers. All the answers to your questions are yes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right:

You iterate all subsets of a sorted set of `n` numbers.
For each subset you test in `O(n log n)` if its is a solution. (how ever you do this)
After you have all this solutions you looking for the one with exact `S` elements with the smalest sum.

The way you write it, the complexity would be `O(2^n * n log n) * O(log (2^n)) = O(2^n * n^2 log n)`. `O(log (2^n)) = O(n)` is for searching the minimum solution, and you do this every round of the for loop with worst case `i=n/2` and every subset is a solution.

Now Im not sure if you mixing `O()` and `o()` up.
`2^n O(nlogn*n)=o(2^n n²)` is only right if you mean `2^n O(nlog(n*n))`.
`f=O(g)` means, the complexity of `f` is not bigger than the complexity of `g`.
`f=o(g)` means the complexity of `f` is smaller than the complexity of `g`.

So `2^n O(nlogn*n) = O(2^n n logn^2) = O(2^n n * 2 logn) = O(2^n n logn) < O(2^n n^2)`

*Notice*: `O(g) = o(h)` is never a good notation. You will (most likly every time) find a function `f` with `f=o(h)` but `f != O(g)`, if `g=o(h)`.

*Improvements*:
If I understand your algorithm right, you can speed it a little up. You know the size of the subset you looking for, so only look at all the subsets that have the size `S`. The worst case is `S=n/2`, so `C(n,n/2) ~ 2^(n-1)` will not reduce the complexity but saves you a factor 2.
You can also just save a solution and check if the next solution is smaller. this way you get the smallest solution without serching for it again. So the complexity would be `O(2^n * n log n)`.

Comment: I supposed that in the worst case that the set is of size n. Enumerate all the subsets of size s (oCn, 1Cn, 2Cn,....nCn). 2^n*o(nlogn)*o(n):  where testing a solution spends o(nlogn) and searching for the minimum spends o(n).  2^n*o(nlogn)*o(n)= o(2^n*n*n*logn)> o(2^n* n^2). This complexity must be = O*(2^n)

Comment: if you not now the minimum size of any solution, you are right. then you have to enumerate all subsets. what do you mean by "this complexity must be = O*(2^n)"? which complexity?

Comment: The complexity of problem on sets must be O*(2^n) refring to the link section subset problems O( p(n)* 2^n)=o*(2^n) where p(n) is a polynomial function

Comment: This is here the case for `p(n) = n^2 log n`. But not all problems on sets have a complexity of `O(2^n)`. If you want tou check if there is a pair `(a,b)`in your set with `a-b < c` for any fixed `c`, the complexity is only `O(n^2)`.